# Unity Editor wont open

Tags: unity

When attempting to open an old project or create and open a new project unity won't open. The hub will open and when you choose a project it will close and then nothing will happen. Also when a new project it will state the unity version for the new project as unknown. I have tried uninstalling, deleting all the files under the registry editor, and also removing the files from the appdata and reinstalling and it doesn't appear to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug to take up with Unity's tech support.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can often happen when your graphics driver not working properly. Here are some ways to fix your graphics driver.

**One:**

Because of hibernating your PC for long time sometimes the graphics driver won't work. Try to fix this by restarting or shutting down your computer.

**Two:**

Try updating your graphics driver from the the driver company’s website or from Windows Update.

**Three:**

If you are starting the Unity up for the first time, you need to log into an account first. If you don’t have one you can create one [here](https://id.unity.com/en/conversations/ab2e8489-dc99-4ea4-91e9-e14bd33ec1c3019f).

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with my VPN service, you might have the same problem as well. I don't know why, but if I have my VPN turned on Unity won't open up (or will crash, or something like that). The workaround is to turn off the VPN while you are working with Unity or replace your custom client with OpenVPN that seems to work nicely with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know much about it, but what I know ( **In my experience**), I'll share it.

**The Problem happened to me because yesterday I downloaded & Installed Unity Pro 2020.xfx. from a website.
(Cracked one).**

I did it because of curiosity.
Today when i was working on a sample project, suddenly unity closed.
I tried to open it many times with no luck.
I searched for solution online, but no luck.

**Then I did the following-

1. I deleted the Unity_lic file from C:\ProgramData\Unity
2. I uninstalled the cracked Unity ( Going to Control Panel>> Uninstall a program and uninstalled the unity ( Only cracked unity will show there, simply named Unity)
3. I installed Unity Hub again. ( Remember, I didn't uninstalled the previous Unity Hub, just overwritten it by installing again. I had the Unity hub setup file downloaded, if you don't have it, simply download from unity website)
4. I opened Unity Hub, I got a window where it said I don't have a valid licence. I selected ACTIVATE NEW LICENCE(or something I don't remembered) Then Choosed Personal.
   And that's it.
   I changed a projects Unity Version to the Version I installed from Unity Hub( Check on Installs tab).
   And when I clicked on the project,
   It just opened.
   The problem solved in my case.**